# Fans By AgeGroup in Percentage SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, percentage

Hey guys I need some help, I can't get the execution right...

I have two queries that get me the results I need to get the right percentage.

1st query:

```
Select Date, AgeGroup,SUM(NumberOfFans) From FansPerGenderAge WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from FansPerGenderAge) GROUP BY AgeGroup;
```

Results:

```
2018-10-16|13-17|20332
2018-10-16|18-24|206787
2018-10-16|25-34|347581
2018-10-16|35-44|188335
2018-10-16|45-54|91804
2018-10-16|55-64|48793
2018-10-16|65+|67379
```

2nd query:

```
Select SUM(NumberOfFans) From FansPerGenderAge WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from FansPerGenderAge);
```

Results:

```
971011
```

I need to divide the NumberOfFans results in query 1, by the result from query two

And the end results should display AgeGroup and PercentageOfFans grouped by AgeGroup...

Any thoughts?

I tried simple things like:

```
SELECT AgeGroup, Round(AgeGroup * 100.0 / SUM(NumberOfFans), 4) FROM FansPerGenderAge WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from FansPerGenderAge) GROUP BY AgeGroup;

13-17|0.0639
18-24|0.0087
25-34|0.0072
35-44|0.0186
45-54|0.049
55-64|0.1127
65+|0.0965
```

But that's not the right percentage when the calculations are done manually.

The answer for age group 13-17 should be 0.020939

Comment: Needs sample table definitions and date (preferably as insert statements for easy copy and pasting into a database) and desired results for that sample.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Have a look at the information available for the "sqlite" tag you used, on how to provide a good [mre] for SQLITE questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `Cross Join` and `Subquery` to get your desired result

```
select AgeGroup,CAST(SUMNumberOfFans1 AS FLOAT)/SUMNumberOfFans2 
from 
(Select Date, 
AgeGroup,
SUM(NumberOfFans) SUMNumberOfFans1
From FansPerGenderAge 
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from FansPerGenderAge) 
GROUP BY AgeGroup) a
CROSS JOIN (
Select 
SUM(NumberOfFans) SUMNumberOfFans2
From FansPerGenderAge 
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from FansPerGenderAge)) b
```